# Cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL using SSL + Golang from Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

Google says you can connect to Google Cloud SQL using Golang and the `go-sql-driver` like so:

```
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user@cloudsql(project-id:instance-name)/dbname")
```

ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/reference

... However, this (for me) generates a x509 certificate error:

> x509: certificate is valid for projectName:instanceName, not
>   projectName

I cannot figure out how to solve this. Adding the instance name again (even though it's already there) in the connection string does not help, nor is correct according to Google's own docs.

Has anyone managed to make this work? What is wrong?

Comment: I'm hoping you can share more info about your setup. Are you running on App Engine? Are you running first/second generation?

Comment: Thanks for the response... solved in the question below. :)

Comment: By the way, this was for first generation, but I'm running into this error trying to make it work on second generation: `TLS requested but server does not support TLS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you connecting with SSL? This error message indicates that must set the `ServerName` property when you register your custom TLSConfig with the mysql driver, **in addition to** specifying the `project-id:instance-name` inside `sql.Open()`.

e.g. Use the TLS setup [from the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterTLSConfig), but add a `ServerName` in your call to `RegisterTLSConfig`:

```
mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("custom", &tls.Config{
            RootCAs:      rootCertPool,
            Certificates: clientCert,
            ServerName:   "projectName:instanceName",
        })
```

Then append `?tls=nameOfYourCustomTLSConfig`

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user@cloudsql(project-id:instance-name)/dbname?tls=custom")
```

Comment: Ah, got it. I couldn't find this information anywhere. Database connection finally successful! I will relay this information to Google support.

Comment: @BenGuild Great to hear! So did you have custom SSL code in and around your `sql.Open()` call?

Comment: Yes, hence the prompt about the certificate. ;)