# "TLS requested but server does not support TLS" error with Google Cloud SQL (2nd generation) from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

I'm running into an issue in re-using my connection string (resolved here ... [Cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL using SSL + Golang from Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259595/cannot-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-using-ssl-golang-from-google-app-engine) ...) from connecting to a **Google Cloud SQL** generation one instance while trying to connect to a generation two instance. I'm receiving this error: `TLS requested but server does not support TLS`

**I can't figure out how to get around this,** and the documentation is pretty scarce.

I caught the fact that `Instance connection name` follows a different structure on generation two, but that doesn't seem like the issue. Has anyone solved this? I'm connecting from Golang.

Comment: Can you share the entire connection string you are using (you can mask out the project / instance name parts)?

Comment: `user:password@cloudsql(copiedPastedInstanceConnectionName)/databaseName?charset=charset&collation=collation&tls=tlsConfigName&parseTime=true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL level SSL is not currently supported between App Engine Standard Environment and Cloud SQL Second Generation instances.

Communication between App Engine Standard Environment and Cloud SQL is already encrypted so using MySQL level SSL does not add a lot of value, though I can understand that doing application level SSL can add some peace of mind since what happens between Cloud SQL and App Engine is opaque.

I'll try to see if this is something we can change.

Comment: You could at least change the documentation, ha. :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I've lost a lot of time on this today.

Comment: For the record, putting this in the documentation and mentioning that such traffic is already encrypted would be quite helpful in designing infrastructure correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Sorry for the pain.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915508/how-to-filter-app-engine-connections-by-host-with-google-cloud-sql-second-genera — Also, you should probably remove this if it's not supported: "For security, it is recommended to always use SSL encryption when connecting to your instance. For more information, see Configuring SSL"

Comment: SSL and cloud proxy now supported

Comment: Is SSL necessary, though, considering what @Vadim said?