# Connecting to CloudSQL from App Engine (Second Generation CloudSQL) GO

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

Love the Stack, My first post out of complete frustration.   Thanks for you comments!

- Created App Engine Project
- Created Second Generation MySQL Instance in my App Engine Project
- Created Database in the MySQL Instance
- In App Engine, I activate the --> Google Cloud Shell <--.  ( I am working at a command prompt in my console.cloud.google.com)

I have copied this basic GO program to connect to my MySQL instance.

I build it and run it.
go build mysqlexample.go
./mysqlexample

I have not been able to achieve a successful connection.  You can see all the various connection strings that I have tried and to the right of them is the response I get.

I can connect from my local windows machine using mysql admin.

Help?

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
    )

func main() {

    const dbIP = "104.xxx.xx.x"
    const dbInstanceName =  "esp-1-dev:us-central1:espdev"
    const dbName = "servpro"
    const dbUserName = "root"
    const dbPassword = "xxxxxxx"

    const dbOpenString = dbUserName + ":" + dbPassword + "@/" + dbInstanceName + "/" + dbName  //GETS RESPONSE default addr for network 'AppEngine:Zone:Project' unknown
    //const dbOpenString = dbUserName + "@cloudsql(" + dbInstanceName + ")/" + dbName   //GETS RESPONSE  dial cloudsql: unknown network cloudsql
    //const dbOpenString = dbUserName + "@/"  //+ "?parseTime=true&loc=UTC"                 //GETS RESPONSE  getsockopt: connection refused
    //const dbOpenString = dbUserName + ":" + dbPassword + "@tcp(" + dbIP + ":3306)/" + dbName  //GETS RESPONSE  dial tcp 104.xxx.xxx.x:3306: getsockopt: connection timed out

    //  Got this from stack overflow.  GoDocs are not updated to reflect 2nd Gen databases.
    //  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890022/tls-requested-but-server-does-not-support-tls-error-with-google-cloud-sql-2nd
    //user:password@cloudsql(copiedPastedInstanceConnectionName)/d‌​atabaseName?charset=‌​charset&collation=co‌​llation&tls=tlsConfi‌​gName&parseTime=true
    //First Generation Connection String    
        //username:password@cloudsql(appID:CloudSQLInstance)/databasename?parseTime=true&loc=UTC

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbOpenString);
    defer db.Close()

    log.Println("Attempting Ping of database....")

    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("db.Ping() failed:  " + dbOpenString)
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Success!")
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't say if you're connecting from App Engine Standard or App Engine Flex. I suspect you are connecting from App Engine Flex but reading App Engine Standard docs/posts. Please confirm.

Comment: I am working in the Google Cloud Shell.   Make the program, build it, run it.   I do not yet have the option to use Flex until I deploy the solution and add that to the yaml.    I have been doing this cloud shell environment as I work thur all the GO examples.   Now I want to talk to cloud sql and  getting stuck.   I think now that I am battling against google cloud shell.   I will deploy my app and turn on flex tonight and post the results.   The connection strings below are not working in  cloud shell but at least the flex connection string gives me a new message... no such file directory

Comment: You should make that more clear in your post. In that case you should **not** be following the App Engine instructions as they are for connecting from App Engine. Connecting from Cloud Shell is a bit more complicated, you would need to download and run the Cloud SQL Proxy in the shell in order to connect (using the same connection string I posted from App Engine Flex)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following are the correct connection strings, but they differ depending on which version of App Engine you are connecting from.

App Engine Standard:

```
user:password@cloudsql(INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME)/dbname
```

App Engine Flexible:

```
user:password@unix(/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME)/dbname
```

Comment: Thank you Vadim, your guidance has helped and I have the unix connection string working on a deployed app engine flex environment.    I am still be blocked on Google Cloud Shell but I am happy to get this working.    This was the most helpful page in google docs which I got to by searching your example connection strings.   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-sql

Answer (score 5):

If you are migrating to the second generation Go App Engine (Golang 1.11) change your connection string from:

`user:password@cloudsql(instanceID)/db`

to

`user:password@unix(/cloudsql/instanceID)/db`

Answer (score 2):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-sql

For new people to GO, App Engine and CloudSQL just writing the simplest GO program to connect and communicate with your CloudSQL 2nd Gen database is frustrating!

You have choices to make, App Eng or App Eng Flex, SQL 1st or 2nd Gen....   Depending on the combination connection strings are different.   All of google's documentation when you search drives you to first gen SQL and App Engine without flex because this is what is predominantly in production.  Make sure you are reading Flex documentation if you are doing that.  Make sure you are reading 2nd Gen docs if doing that.   Sometimes they are entirely different docs, sometimes the documentation is stacked on a page and you have to goto the bottom to see about the newer stuff  2nd gen sql and app eng flex.

CloudShell is tricky, I still cannot compile GO and talk to SQL 2nd here.   I am successfully talking to cloud sql 2nd gen from a deployed app engine flex WITH A SQL PROXY RUNNING,  you have to use SQL PROXY.   You have to go thru the setup for this create users on appengine and SQL.

This is my working program.

```
package main

import (
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
"log"
"fmt"
"net/http"
)

func healthCheckHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
fmt.Fprint(w, "ok")
}

func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
http.HandleFunc("/_cloudshellProxy/_ah/health", healthCheckHandler)
log.Print("Listening on port 8080")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}


func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

const dbIP = "104.xxx.xxx.x"
const dbInstanceName =  "projectname:us-central1:sqlinstance"
const dbName = "servxxx"
const dbUserName = "sqlproxysuser"
const dbPassword = "xxxRockxxx"


if r.URL.Path != "/" {
    http.NotFound(w, r)
    return
}
fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello SQL!  Hello?")
fmt.Fprint(w, "\n")

const dbOpenString = dbUserName + ":" + dbPassword + "@unix(/cloudsql/" + dbInstanceName + ")/" + dbName 
//const dbOpenString = dbUserName + ":" + dbPassword + "@cloudsql(" + dbInstanceName + ")/" + dbName 

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
//-=- SQL OPEN Statement,  per docs, DOES NOT return an error ever
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbOpenString);
defer db.Close()

err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Failed Connection" + "  " + dbOpenString)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "\n")
    fmt.Fprint(w, err)
    return
} else {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "SUCCESSFUL CONNECTION" + "  " + dbOpenString)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "\n")
}

_, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exercisecloudsql101 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, description TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id))")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "CREATE TABLE failed:")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "\n")
    fmt.Fprint(w, err) 
    fmt.Fprint(w, "\n")
} else {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "SUCCESSFUL CreateTable" + "  " + dbOpenString)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "\n")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have run in to the same problem of connecting to a cloud SQL instance. One variant that I got working on my windows localhost environment is below. The IP of my localhost needs to be added to Authorized networks for the db instance.

Windows localhost connect over tcp:

```
user:password@tcp(104.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306)/dbname
```