# Mysql Connection Issue while deploying GO code in Google App Engine (Flexible Environment)

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-flexible

I am facing Mysql Connection issue , while migrating my code from Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment ( Google App Engine) .

I have even tried following : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-sql

Stackoverflow link :
[Connecting to CloudSQL from App Engine (Second Generation CloudSQL) GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943098/connecting-to-cloudsql-from-app-engine-second-generation-cloudsql-go/47926441#4792644)

But still not able to solve the issue . My case is :

I have even tried deploying the code given in above stackoverflow link (with my Cloud Sql) to test if it works . But in every case I am getting an error saying :

```
dial unix /cloudsql/butter-142812:us-central1:test: connect: no such file or directory

Where for me dbInstanceName  = butter-142812:us-central1:test
```

But everytime I am hitting the same problem . Can you please point out if I am missing something ?

I trying to deploy my app on Flexible Environment .

Comment: is the Cloud SQL proxy running on your Flexible instance? are you using a custom Dockerfile? please provide more information....

Comment: @Gal Ben-Haim : yes the Cloud SQL proxy is running on my Flexible instance (as I am not doing anything innovative but just following the documentation religiously) . Do let me know if there is a way to verify if Cloud SQL proxy is running or not . 

No , I am not using any custom docker file.